# Where can I find sources for Gergonne's research on the fundamental relations among classes?

Tags: mathematics, logic

Alfred Tarski writes

> The whole of the old traditional logic...can almost entirely be reduced to the theory of the fundamental relations among classes, that is, to a small fragment of the entire theory of classes. (page 39)

In a footnote he remarks that

> These relations were first investigated in an exhaustive manner by J. D. GERGONNE (1771-1859)

I'm aware that [Gergonne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Diez_Gergonne) started his own journal *[Annales de Mathématiques Pures et Appliquées](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annales_de_Gergonne)*, but I don't know where in his journal (or elsewhere) he published his results on the fundamental relations among classes. I have found some of these [Annales on Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/gergonne-annales).

Where can I find sources for Gergonne's published work on the fundamental relations among classes?

---

Tarski, A. (1996). Introduction to Logic and to the Methodology of the Deductive Sciences. Translated by Olaf Helmer. Dover Publications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Essai de dialectique rationnelle (1816-17)](https://eudml.org/doc/79642).

A brief description can be found in Leila Haaparanta (editor), [The Development of Modern Logic (2009)](https://books.google.it/books?id=0jXavKsArnIC&pg=PA133), **Ch.3 : Logic from Humanism to Kant**.